# Web-part, search-and-replace function in SP2013

Tags: 2013, development, visual-web-part, web

I need to implement web-part search-and-replace function to act on the content of Word docs in a SP2013 library. Any guidance most welcome, its not my familiar environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement web part in farm solution. This will enable to use server side code and also Microsoft Office Interop assemblies to work with doc and docx documents. As a disadvantage of this approach, the office package must be installed on the servers.
Or you can use other libraries, for example, Open XML SDK, without needed MS Office installed.

Second approach is create SharePoint Provider-hosted apps and realize Client Web Part (App Part).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use SPFile if I converted the file to plain text first, which I might do because XML is much easier to deal with than a Word file. Now I need save the changes back out to the library!